# Yahoo Finance API

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance

How to fetch the complete list of Yahoo Finance Stock symbol using YQL ???

not trying to fetch a single stock quote. I am trying to find the whole complete list of available stock symbol. E.g. all Stock Symbol from NYSE, NASDAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo Finance may not help you much in this. You can get all the stock symbol from the exchange and later use the standard stock symbol in Yahoo Finance API or any other finance API to get the required details.

You can use the following link to download the list as CSV http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx.

You might have to read the Terms and conditions, before using them.