# Yahoo Finance API all stocks?

Tags: yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I'm trying to get multiple stock quotes from Yahoo Finance API (http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=STOCK_NAME&f=nsl1op&e=.csv), 
 but I don't want to mention the stock's name.

Is there a way to get the top 100 or 1000 stocks? If not, is there another API that does do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an api from NASDAQ
https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=6000&exchange=NASDAQ
Result is sth like this

```
{
               "symbol":"TSM",
               "name":"Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing Company Ltd.",
               "lastsale":"$118.88",
               "netchange":"0.46",
               "pctchange":"0.388%",
               "marketCap":"616,520,714,880",
               "url":"/market-activity/stocks/tsm"
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

[Helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015016/yahoo-finance-api) You can download latest stock exchange data for Nasdaq/NYSE/AMEX from [here](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx).

and then use [YQL example](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance%20.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22%20MSFT%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env) to call symbols for relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo Finance API shut down awhile ago. I've been using the [Intrinio Stock API](https://intrinio.com) and it's been great.

Usage is simple:

https://api.intrinio.com/prices?identifier=AAPL

(along with your basic auth tokens)

returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "2018-09-06",
      "open": 226.61,
      "high": 227.35,
      "low": 221.3,
      "close": 223.1,
      "volume": 33428527,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 226.61,
      "adj_high": 227.35,
      "adj_low": 221.3,
      "adj_close": 223.1,
      "adj_volume": 33428527
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-09-05",
      "open": 228.99,
      "high": 229.67,
      "low": 225.1,
      "close": 226.87,
      "volume": 33332960,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 228.99,
      "adj_high": 229.67,
      "adj_low": 225.1,
      "adj_close": 226.87,
      "adj_volume": 33332960
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-09-04",
      "open": 228.41,
      "high": 229.18,
      "low": 226.63,
      "close": 228.36,
      "volume": 27390132,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 228.41,
      "adj_high": 229.18,
      "adj_low": 226.63,
      "adj_close": 228.36,
      "adj_volume": 27390132
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-08-31",
      "open": 226.51,
      "high": 228.87,
      "low": 226,
      "close": 227.63,
      "volume": 43340134,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 226.51,
      "adj_high": 228.87,
      "adj_low": 226,
      "adj_close": 227.63,
      "adj_volume": 43340134
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-08-30",
      "open": 223.25,
      "high": 228.26,
      "low": 222.4,
      "close": 225.03,
      "volume": 48793824,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 223.25,
      "adj_high": 228.26,
      "adj_low": 222.4,
      "adj_close": 225.03,
      "adj_volume": 48793824
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-08-29",
      "open": 220.15,
      "high": 223.49,
      "low": 219.41,
      "close": 222.98,
      "volume": 27254804,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 220.15,
      "adj_high": 223.49,
      "adj_low": 219.41,
      "adj_close": 222.98,
      "adj_volume": 27254804
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-08-28",
      "open": 219.01,
      "high": 220.54,
      "low": 218.92,
      "close": 219.7,
      "volume": 22776766,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 219.01,
      "adj_high": 220.54,
      "adj_low": 218.92,
      "adj_close": 219.7,
      "adj_volume": 22776766
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-08-27",
      "open": 217.15,
      "high": 218.74,
      "low": 216.33,
      "close": 217.94,
      "volume": 20525117,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 217.15,
      "adj_high": 218.74,
      "adj_low": 216.33,
      "adj_close": 217.94,
      "adj_volume": 20525117
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-08-24",
      "open": 216.6,
      "high": 216.9,
      "low": 215.11,
      "close": 216.16,
      "volume": 18476356,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 216.6,
      "adj_high": 216.9,
      "adj_low": 215.11,
      "adj_close": 216.16,
      "adj_volume": 18476356
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-08-23",
      "open": 214.65,
      "high": 217.05,
      "low": 214.6,
      "close": 215.49,
      "volume": 18883224,
      "ex_dividend": 0,
      "split_ratio": 1,
      "adj_factor": 1,
      "adj_open": 214.65,
      "adj_high": 217.05,
      "adj_low": 214.6,
      "adj_close": 215.49,
      "adj_volume": 18883224
    }
  ],
  "result_count": 9526,
  "page_size": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "total_pages": 953,
  "api_call_credits": 1
}
```